# Is commenting faster than th:remove="all-but-first"?

Tags: thymeleaf

There's an example in the [Thymeleaf docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html) that I'm curious about.

Is commenting out a block using Thymeleaf-style commenting faster than using `th:remove="all-but-first"`?

Example:

```
<table>
    <tr th:each="user : ${users}">
        <td th:text="${user.name}">Jamie Dimon</td>
    </tr>
    <!--/* Hidden from evaluation -->
    <tr>
        <td>Jeff Bezos</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Warren Buffett</td>
    </tr>
    <!--*/-->
</table>
```

vs.

```
<table th:remove="all-but-first">
    <tr th:each="user : ${users}">
        <td th:text="${user.name}">Jamie Dimon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jeff Bezos</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Warren Buffett</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In both cases, prototyping would show the same HTML, but I am wondering whether the low precedence of `th:remove` would make it less desirable since it would be removing the tags after evaluating the `th:each`.

Comment: Yes commenting will always be faster than showing it then removing it. Best way is to run a loop and have it stop after the first item.

Comment: So what's the point of `th:remove="all-but-first"`?  Just slightly shorter but without the room for a comment like "Hidden from evaluation"?

Comment: Sorry not sure what you're asking?

Comment: Why use “all-but-first”?

Comment: Note: operator precedence only matters when you are evaluating operators/attributes on the same tag.  The low operator precedence of `th:remove` has no bearing on attributes that appear in child tags (and therefore is still evaluated before the `th:each`).  As for actual speed, I can't comment on that.

Comment: Ah, yes - good point about the precedence and the tag order. Still not sure whether I'd use `all-but-first`.